# Microsoft Word 2013 Suddenly Erases Page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, office365

This has happened four times now.  I will be typing along, minding my own business, when all of a sudden, the document I am working on starts erasing itself, racing upwards from the bottom all the way to the top.  It cannot be stopped while it is happening, and once it is done, I am locked out of doing anything in Word, including closing it out.  I have to open Task Manager and hard shut it down, and start all over.

Last time it happened, I ran a Norton NIS scan of my system which found some potential threats embedded in .zip files in My Documents folder, but nothing in the commonly infected areas of the computer.  I got rid of those threats, but it happened again just this morning.  I ran another scan and there was nothing, so it appears to be a buggy product.  However, googling around, I can't find another instance of this occurring.

Does anyone know whether this is a known issue, and if so how to fix it?

Comment: Kind of sounds like your keyboard has a stuck (backspace) key.  Try a new keyboard.  Also, have you ensured all 3rd party Word/Office add-ons are disabled?

Comment: Try setting up a test environment. Type a bunch of stuff until it happens. Once it does then unplug your keyboard right away to see if it stops the backspacing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.

It might be a stuck backspace key, except it has happened irrespective of whether I am typing at the moment or not.

As for the test environment, it happens infrequently, like every several days, and unexpectedly, so I don't see how I can set up a reliable test to make it happen.  Also, it's happening on a laptop, so I can't separate the keyboard.